# Using BeautifulSoup4, find every time text starts with a certain symbol in a website

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape price for an item from a website using python.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://..."
result = requests.get(URL)

doc = BeautifulSoup(result.text, "html.parser")
prices = doc.find_all(???)
print(prices)
```

In question marks I know I can write the full string which to look for, but I want so that it finds every time there is a text that starts with "$".

Is it possible, if so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`regular expression`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) to catch the tags that starts with certain character as below:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<p>$Show me</p>
<p>I am invisible</p>
<p>me too</p>
<p>$Show me too</p>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
result = soup.find_all("p", text=re.compile("^\$"))
# -> [<p>$Show me</p>, <p>$Show me too</p>]
```

Note that I used `\` operated before `$` since dollar sign itself is a special character. See [regular expression syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, this works! Saw this solution without the backslash so was confused why it didn't work.

Comment: @KristapsĀlmanis you are welcome, if it solved your issue please see this thread on [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)